# pdfTeX error: cannot open Type 1 font file for reading

Tags: fonts, errors, pdftex

### Environment

- OS: Mac OS X 10.10.4
- TeX Live: 2015 Basic
- Editor: Sublime Text 3 w/ LaTeXTools

### Preamble of tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt,MSc,twoside]{muthesis}
% The tex template of University of Manchester

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pslatex}
```

### Question

When I compiled the tex file, the following error appeared:

```
pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ucrr8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
```

I checked the log file and found the error:

```
{/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ucrr8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I found `ucrr8a.pfb` available to download from CTAN but I do not know where to locate it or do I miss any package?

Comment: You missed *lots* of packages if you only installed Basic. You will find thing *much* easier with a complete installation. `courier` is part of TeX Live. But it is not so critical that it is included in Basic. It is, after all, just a font.

Comment: @Zelong I'm not very sure because I don't use Mac, but you can try this path: `{/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/courier}`. Does this work for you?

Comment: @AboAmmar If you add fonts directly, they should *not* be installed into the main TEXMF tree. If you use `tlmgr` to do the install, it will use something like that, but that is quite different. If you download from CTAN, they go in TEXMFLOCAL. However, this is not a good solution in this case because many other packages are also going to be missing....

Comment: @cfr Thank you very much. The problem is due to missing `courier`. It usually takes me efforts to figure out what is missing when I use a template . Thanks for your advice of installing a complete TeX Live.

Comment: @AboAmmar It did not work. I think @cfr is right, I need to configure other settings more than simply put the fonts in the directory. Install `courier` package or install a complete TeX Live helps.

Comment: @Zelong Do *not* drop things from CTAN (or elsewhere) into the directories managed by the TeX Live Manager (`tlmgr` or TeX Live Utility or whatever). If you really needed to install something like this independently, you can. But there are specific locations for that. And, as you say, merely putting the files in the right places is not enough. Even if this wasn't fonts, it would not be enough. And fonts are extra work again.

Comment: If you frequently use templates and even if you do not, only having Basic installed is going to be very frustrating. Unless you are desperately short of space, a complete installation is simply much easier to work with.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for your advice. I agree that I should not mess up with the system directory manually. By the way, I think the question is solved but no answer is posted, should I delete the question? How could I marked it as "Solved"?

Comment: @Zelong I've added a quick answer covering the comments which I think solved the problem. Let me know if not. (This must be a duplicate but answering was easier....)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Basic scheme is pretty minimal and lacks a lot of packages which you are likely to need, especially if you often compile 'templates' of one sort or another. Even if you don't, you are likely to want to use many of those packages.

Unless disk space is a real problem, it is much easier to just install the full version of TeX Live and then you know that you have (almost) everything you are likely to need.

If that's not an option, you can use the TeX Live Manager (`tlmgr` or TeX Live Utility, perhaps) to install additional packages on a case-by-case basis. But there are likely to be many, many such cases and this option is, therefore, likely to be rather frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

It’s harder to find the TeX Live package containing a file than it should be.  However, here are some instructions to find the right package more generally, and not just tell you where this one is.  The place to start is with [a filename search on CTAN.](https://www.ctan.org/search?phrase=ucrr8a.pfb&ext=true&_PKG=&_AUTHORS=&_TOPICS=&_FILES=&FILES=on&_PORTAL=&max=16)

In this case, it appears to find three different copies of the file in the directory, but these are symbolic links to [the same directory.](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/base35/pfb)  Going up one directory level shows that the file is part of the [Base35 package.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/urw-base35)  This doesn’t have a TeX Live package that you can install with `tlmgr`, but you can download an archive and extract it to your local TeX tree.

You get the directory in which to install the new files by typing `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` in the console.  You might additionally want to create a subdirectory, such as `base35`, so that all the files from this package are in the same place and you can easily delete them.  After installing any legacy fonts, you want to run

```
sudo texhash
sudo updmap-sys
```

However, looking further shows that your fonts are being set by `pslatex.sty`, which is part of `pslatex`, [whose readme says](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pslatex) that you must install the PostScript fonts from [`psnfss`.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss)  This does come as part of a package, “TeX Live as psnfss”, so `tlmgr install psnfss` should work for you.

However, the authors of `pslatex` also say that it is “widely considered obsolete.”  If you are required to use those specific fonts in PDFTeX, you might still consider replacing `pslatex` with

```
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath, tgheros, tgcursor}
```

Indeed, the search for `base35` helpfully suggested that you check out `tex-gyre`, which contains `tgcursor`, a clone of Courier.

If you can upgrade to LuaLaTeX, you might switch to OpenType fonts, such as

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures = TeX }
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} % Times
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros} % Helvetica
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor} % Courier
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math} % Times
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I use basic out of principle because I find "just install everything" such a terrible way to handle a system. Your CTAN filename search remark made me realise the pbf I was missing came from the utopia font package.

Answer (score 2):

Install the missing `courier` package:

```sh
sudo tlmgr install courier
```

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody lands on this page with the same/similar problem, but a Linux distribution, solving this class of problems is very easy.

Install apt-file, and update the cache:

```sh
$ apt install apt-file
$ apt-file update
```

Then just search the filename, and install the package:

```sh
$ apt-file search ucrr8a.pfb
texlive-fonts-recommended: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/courier/ucrr8a.pfb
$ apt install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org), you can install the package `texlive-fonts-recommended`. It contains the necessary file `putb8a.pfb`. Execute

```
sudo port install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

to install it.

In order to find a package, that contains a file you need please use [Debian's package search](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages). The search field is in the top right corner of the page.